# TextBox1 unable to display changing result every 1 second

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display selected result which I get from my `DataGridView` into `TextBox1` every 1 second after push "SHOW" button , but the problem here is ,it will only display "LANCE" on the TextBox1 after 5 second.

I need `TextBox1` to show YYYYY --> dhghgY -->jttr --> lkukm --> wewerf --> LANCE

How to solve this?

My code as below

```
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
    Dim index As Integer


    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        table.Rows.Add(TextBoxID.Text, TextBoxFN.Text, TextBoxFN.Text, TextBoxAGE.Text)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
        TextBoxID.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxFN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxLN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxAGE.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim newDataRow As DataGridViewRow
        newDataRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
        newDataRow.Cells(0).Value = TextBoxID.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(1).Value = TextBoxFN.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(2).Value = TextBoxLN.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(3).Value = TextBoxAGE.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        table.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

        table.Rows.Add(1, "XXXX", "YYYYY", 21)
        table.Rows.Add(2, "SSDD", "dhghgY", 33)
        table.Rows.Add(3, "fhdt", "jttr", 53)
        table.Rows.Add(4, "jyj", "lkukm,", 19)
        table.Rows.Add(5, "reytr", "wewerf", 36)
        table.Rows.Add(6, "MAN", "LANCE", 63)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table



    End Sub


    Private Sub btnSHOW_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSHOW.Click



        For j As Integer = 0 To 5

            TextBox1.Clear()

            TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value.ToString()

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)


        Next


    End Sub
End Class
```

[Push button "SHOW" and display on Textbox1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDsmm.jpg)

Comment: How about moving your code over into a `Timer` ?

Comment: Are you using [tag:vba] or [tag:vb.net].  They are related but not interchangeable.  I'm assuming you're using [tag:excel]? Does this involve a [tag:userform]?

Comment: It is becase your UI thread is frozen by sleep. I think it will work if you put sleep first then TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1(2,j).Value.ToString(), and you don't need textbox.clear()    @ashleeawg: It's not VBA.

Comment: You should not be using `Thread.Sleep` at all.  Use a `Timer` and handle its `Tick` event.  If you set the `Interval` to 1000 then the event will be raised every 1 second.  You make the appropriate change each time and `Stop` the `Timer` when you're done.

Comment: @CruleD - Dang... I got as far as *"which tag: vba or vb.net?"* then saw the reference to ***rows*** and figured it must be [tag:vba] and realized I had a similar solution sitting here.  There's something to be said for clarity in posting (and for reading the whole way through when answering!)

Comment: Just add `Application.DoEvents()` in your code. To actually refresh the screen

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an **ActiveX textbox** on a **worksheet** within which you want to cycle through **five values**, at te rate of **one per second**, similar to this:

[image: img]

If that's roughly correct, you could **adapt this code** to your needs:

```
Option Explicit
Public schedTime As Date, lastActionID As Byte

Sub startTimer()
    Dim txt As String

    'do something for the one second timer
    Select Case lastActionID
       Case 0: txt = Format(Date, "dddd")
       Case 1: txt = Format(Date, "mmmm")
       Case 2: txt = Format(Date, "d")
       Case 3: txt = Format(Date, "yyyy")
       Case 4: txt = Format(Date, "H:mm am/pm")
    End Select

    'set value of activex textbox on worksheet
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = txt

    'set next action
    lastActionID = lastActionID + 1
    If lastActionID >= 5 Then lastActionID = 0  'produces numbers 0 to 4

    'restart timer
    schedTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime schedTime, "startTimer", , True
End Sub

Sub stopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = ""    'clear textbox
    Application.OnTime schedTime, "startTimer", , False     'cancel timer
End Sub
```

Just place the code into a new module, and on a worksheet create an ActiveX textbox named `TextBox1`.

- Run sub `startTimer` to begin the timer procedure.
- Run sub `stopTimer` to stop the timer procedure.

---

### A couple things to note:

1. The references to the control are **not** [fully qualified](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/) and therefore will be looking for the control on the `ActiveSheet`.
2. There is **no error handling** or code to otherwise deal with potential **timer-related issues**.

   For example, start the timer and then close the workbook with out stopping it...  Try now!  *hehehe,*  kinda freaky the first time you see that happen, eh?

   The timer will keep running *no matter what* until you stop it. Therefore, it's a good idea to call `StopTimer` from the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event in the `ThisWorkbook` module.
3. Running short-interval timers (a few seconds apart or less) like this can impact performance of the worksheet, and can make any further coding a bit of a pain as everything gets interrupted once a second.

Comment: Despite the VBA tag, the code in the question is clearly VB.NET - the question refers to a `DataGridView` so it must be VB.NET - so a VBA solution won;t help.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I wouldn't say *"clearly"*.  People come here because they don't know what they are doing yet... (and often mix up languages, hence the [tag:vba] tag.)  Anyway, I'll leave this answer here because there's no point in wasting it -- others needing a similar solution would likely end up here anyhow (and it was a correct answer for the posted question at the time that I answered it.)  The theory is correct.

Comment: Hi, actually i'm using VB2010. I need VB2010 solution.